# I cannot figure out why the first time I click on item i get expected behavior but when i do this another time i get unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot figure out why the first time I click on the circles to completed state (div with class 'item-no-done') or return it back to the uncompleted state (div with class 'item-done') they work as they have been intended, though, when I do click again I get unexpected behavior (list item 2) or it doesn't occur (list item 1)

[image]

```js
$(function(){

// To complete the list item 
   $('.circle').on('click', function(e){
    var target = $(e.target).parent();
    var text_decoration = target.children('p').addClass('finished');
    var addComplitedCircle = target.children('.circle').attr('class','completed').append('<img src="images/icon-check.svg" class="check">');
    var item_done = target.attr('class','item-done');
    });

  //Make a completed list item to be uncompleted
    $('.check').on('click', function(e){
        var target = $(e.target).parent().parent();
        var $Completedcircle = target.children('.completed');
        var removeComplitedCircle = $Completedcircle.attr('class', 'circle');
        var removeCheckSign = $Completedcircle.children().remove();
        var delete_text_decoration = target.children('p').removeClass('finished');
        var $item_no_done = target.attr('class','item-no-done');
    });

})
```

```html
  <div class="todo_list_area">
    <div class="content">
            <div class="item-done">
                  <div class="completed"> 
                    <img src="images/icon-check.svg" class="check">
                  </div>
              <p class="finished">Make the list item number one</p>
              <div class="close-button-div"> 
                <img src="images/icon-cross.svg" class="close-button">
              </div>
            </div>
          

          <div class="item-no-done">
              <div class="circle"></div>
              <p>Make the list item number one</p>
              <div class="close-button-div"> 
                <img src="images/icon-cross.svg" class="close-button">
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a function like `$('.check').on('click', function(e){` it will not work for elements that are created after the function is loaded. Define it as `$('body').on('click','.check', function(e){` this way, the function gets assigned to body and triggers for element match.

```
$(function(){

  // To complete the list item 
  $('body').on('click','.circle', function(){
    var target = $(this).parent();
    var text_decoration = target.find('p').addClass('finished');
    target.find('.circle').addClass('completed').append('<img src="images/icon-check.svg" class="check">');
    target.removeClass('item-no-done').addClass('item-done');
  });

  //Make a completed list item to be uncompleted
  $('body').on('click','.check', function(){
    var target = $(this).parent().parent();
    var $Completedcircle = target.find('.completed');
    $Completedcircle.addClass('circle');
    $Completedcircle.children().remove();
    target.find('p').removeClass('finished');
    target.removeClass('item-done').addClass('item-no-done');
  });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a click callback for every '.circle' and '.check' elements available only once the document is loaded. Any new element with the classes will not have the click callback.

In order for your new element `addComplitedCircle` to have the click callback you have to set it when creating the element:

```
var addComplitedCircle = target.children('.circle').attr('class','completed').append('<img src="images/icon-check.svg" class="check">');
addComplitedCircle.on('click', <same function>)
```

For your particular case I would suggest you to look at [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

> will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$( ".todo_list_area" ).on( "click", ".item-done", function( event ) {
  var clickedElement = $(this);
  <code to 'undone' item> 
});
$( ".todo_list_area" ).on( "click", ".item-no-done", function( event ) {
  var clickedElement = $(this);
  <code to 'done' item> 
});
```

This will set only two events instead of one event for every change in your todo list.